# How to retrieve time without the offset number at the end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timestamp

`Time.now` will produce something like:

`2013-07-24 22:23:08 -0700`

I want:

`2013-07-24 22:23:08`

for subsequent entry into a DB. Gotta be something simple, but I didn't find it in [Time docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html). Writing `Time.now.to_s[0..19]` sounds like bad programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get this by

```
Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db)
```

You can find different formats for to_formatted_s from [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/DateTime/Conversions/to_formatted_s)

**or**

```
Time.now.strftime("%F %T")
```

Hope this could help you